# How can I perform a low-level analysis of a performance degradation?

Tags: performance, arm, cpu, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture

For example, I have a large linear function (1 basic block, ~1000 instructions)
which is called many times. After some fiddling with compiler options I've got
an unexpected 10% performance degradation on Cortex-A57. Presumably it is due to
a little different instruction scheduling. I'd like to investigate the problem
deeper and find out what instruction combination causes unnecessary pipeline
stalls. But I have no idea how I could do that. I guess, I need a very detailed
execution trace to understand what happens, though I'm not sure if it is
possible to get such a trace.

So, the question is: What tools can I use to investigate such low-level
performance problems? How can I determine what prevents the CPU from executing
maximum number of instructions every cycle?

**PS** I'm mostly interested in Cortex-A57 cores, but I'd appreciate useful
information on any other core or even a different architecture.

**PPS** The function accesses the memory, but it is expected that almost all memory
accesses hit the cache. The assumption is confirmed by `perf stat -e r42,r43`
(`L1D_CACHE_REFILL_LD` and `L1D_CACHE_REFILL_ST` events).

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question already - studying the [microarchitectural PMU events](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0488c/BIIDBAFB.html) with perf is indeed one of the most informative things to do. Knowing A57, it's probably a subtle change in code alignment making suboptimal conditions for the branch predictor.

Comment: PMU can sometimes say what is the problem but AFAIK it cannot say where is the problem. Moreover, PMU event list for A57 is much shorter than for A53. I wish A57 supported "Attributable Performance Impact Event"s, but it seems that it doesn't.

Comment: Did you only modify the compiler options? Or did you make any code changes?

Comment: No code changes. In fact, in both cases the mentioned function consists of the same number of the same instructions. The only differences are instruction ordering, registers being used, and addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Tools: I'm most familiar with Intel compilers and tools but notice there are several similar tools out there for the ARM ecosystem. Here are some techniques I recommend.

USE YOUR COMPILER It has many options that can give you a very good idea of what is going on.

- Disable any optimizations (compiler option) while compiling your original code. This will tell you if the issue is related to code generation optimizations.
- Do a before and after ASM dump, and compare. You may find code differences that you already know are suspect.
- Make sure you are not including any debugging information. Debugging inserts check points and other things that can potentially impact the performance of your code. These bits of code will also change the execution of the code through the pipeline
- Change the compiler options one at a time to identify if the issue is related to data or code alignment enforcement, etc. I'm sure you've already done this but am mentioning it for completeness.
- Enable any compiler performance monitoring options that can be dumped to a log file. A lot of useful information can be found in compiler log files. On the other hand, they also contain info that can only be interpreted by those that live on a higher plain of existence, i.e. compiler writers.

USE A TOOL THAT DUMPS PMU EVENTS

- I saw quite a few out there. My apologies for not giving references but you can do a simple search ["tool arm pmu events"](https://www.google.com/#safe=off&q=tool+arm+pmu+events). These can be extremely sophisticated and powerful, e.g. Intel VTune, or very basic and still very powerful, e.g. the command line SEP for x86.
- Take a look at the performance events (PMU events) available to you and figure out which events you want to monitor. You can get these events from the ARM Cortex-A57 processor tech reference (Chapter 11, Performance Monitoring Unit).

USE A PMU DUMPING SDK

- Use an SDK what has functions for acquiring the ARM PMU events. These SDKs provide you with APIs for selecting and acquiring PMU events, giving you very precise control. Inserting this monitoring code may impact the execution of your code, so be careful of its placement. Again, you can find plenty of such SDKs out there with a simple search.

STUDY UP ON PIPELINE DEBUGGING (IF YOU ARE REALLY INTO THIS TYPE OF STUFF)

- Find a good architectural description of the pipeline, including reservation stations, # of ALUs, etc.
- Find a good reference on how to figure out what is going on in the pipeline.  [Here's an example for x86.](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/vtune/performance_analysis_guide.pdf) ARM is a different beast but x86 articles will give you the basics (and more) of what you need to analyze and and what you can do with what you find.

Good luck. Pipeline debugging can be fun but time consuming.

Comment: Thanks! That's a nice overview.